# Changing a property of an ObservableCollection in a ViewModel without selecting it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, observablecollection

In my program I have a `TreeView` that is implemented through a ViewModel by using an `ObservableCollection`. Each collection has a property called `Rank`. This is supposed to serve as the collection item's index.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456690/shifting-nodes-up-and-down-in-a-treeview/19463924?noredirect=1#19463924), I was able to get my `TreeView` nodes to switch places using `ObservableCollection.Move();`

However, after switching the places of the nodes, I need to correct/change the value of the nodes' rank, so that I can continue to manipulate them.

This should help explain what I am doing:

View -- Code-Behind:

```
//Button Click Event -- This makes the Selected Node switch places with the node above it
private void shiftUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //if a node is selected
   if (UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.SelectedItem != null)
   {
       //If the selected Node is not in the 0 position (can not move up anymore)
       if (UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.Collection<TreeViewModel>.IndexOf(UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.SelectedItem) != 0)
       {
           int oldIndex = UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.SelectedItem.Rank;
           int newIndex = oldIndex--;

           UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.Collection<TreeViewModel>.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);

           //**Pseudo code trying to explain what I want to do
           //**get item at specific index and change the Rank value 
           //Collection item at index (newIndex).Rank -= 1;
           //Collection item at index (oldIndex).Rank += 1;
       }
   }
}
```

UserControl -- XAML:

`<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewViewModel.Collection<TreeModel>}" ... />`

How can I correct the `Rank` values after the move?

**EDIT**

As stated above, I have a `Rank` property in the Data Model of my `TreeView`. @Noctis's answer recommends using that property to sort my `TreeView` after the `Rank` values are changed. This is demonstrated by my favorite question on this topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487927/expand-wpf-treeview-to-support-sorting).

I've added the `SortObservableCollection` class to my program, so now all that's left is to manipulate rank values, and sort. Would the correct place to do this be from the code-behind? Basically where the above^ section is from? If that is the case, I get a little confused about the exact calls...

Code-Behind:

```
private void shiftUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //if a node is selected
     if (UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.SelectedItem != null)
     {
         //Moves the selectedNode down one (Up visually, hence shiftUp)
         UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.SelectedItem.Rank--;

         //How would I get the node below the selected one and change the Rank?

         //This would be the call to sort. Which needs to be called for the collection
         //For some reason, sort does not come up for the collection...
         //UCViewModel.TreeViewViewModel.Collection.**Sort(...);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of actually moving your items around, you could change the actual values on your objects ranks (assuming they are public properties), and let the sorting be done automatically for you via the binding ...

**Edit:**
This is embarrassing, and as your comment says, my link is to winforms.

having said that, have a look at this wonderful answers by [rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487927/expand-wpf-treeview-to-support-sorting), [wpf-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943559/wpf-keeping-a-treeview-list-sorted), and the self answered [jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178296/how-do-i-sort-a-wpf-treeview-that-has-items-bound-to-the-properties-of-an-item-s) .

They either implemented a comparer (the direction i was going to with the msdn link), or used the default headers.

That should give you a great start and example on how to do it with your rank.

**Edit**:

On the Xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<TreeView Name="TestTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTree}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" Padding="2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
<Button Command="{Binding SortMe_Command}">Sort</Button>
```

On the view model I have a simple class like this (with rank, for you):

```
public class MyTreeClass
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

I've added rachel's class as is:

```
public class SortableObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> { ...}
```

Property for the binding:

```
public SortableObservableCollection<MyTreeClass> MyTree
    {
        get { return _myTree; }
        set { _myTree = value; }
    }
private SortableObservableCollection<MyTreeClass> _myTree;
```

Command for the action:

> public ICommand SortMe_Command { get; set; }

In the constructor:

```
MyTree = new SortableObservableCollection<MyTreeClass>() {new MyTreeClass(){Name = "One",Rank = 1},
        new MyTreeClass(){Name = "Two",Rank = 2},
        new MyTreeClass(){Name = "Three",Rank = 3}};
        SortMe_Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute_SortMe);
SortMe_Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute_SortMe);
```

And last but not least, the execute method:

```
private void Execute_SortMe(object obj)
    {
        MyTree[0].Rank = 5;
        MyTree[1].Rank = 4;

        MyTree.Sort(node => node.Rank);
    }
```

Now when I click the button, it will change 2 item's rank, and resort the tree according to rank.

In your application, just figure out which one's you're swapping, and you're set ...

Comment: They're public properties declared within the `TreeView`'s model, but how would changing the `Rank` allow them to automatically re-sort? I ask this because I created `Rank`. It doesn't automatically translate to the collection index.

Comment: Well, have a look at this article in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sort.aspx) . You can sort the tree whichever way you want, if you supply your own  TreeViewNodeSorter .

Comment: That article is for Windows Forms

Comment: I've edited my question. I like the "rachel" answer. I understand it, but I am having trouble understanding how to implement it for my program. Please have a look, and let me know if you can lend any assistance. Thank you.